# What kind of Modulation? Who transmits on 850 MHz (LTE-Uplink or GPRS?)?

Tags: rf, high-frequency, digital-modulation, sdr

[image]Hey, I found an interesting Signal on 850MHz (in Germany). It is not symmetric and very strong (relative to many others due to bad antennas). On the right side the bandwith is permanently used, on the left side the bandwith is temporaly used and devided into many slots. Anybody also see sth comparable? I have already looked at sigidwiki. Kind regards.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about the use of a particular radio band, and not about electrical engineering.

Comment: Sennheiser
evolution wireless IEM G4 systems  Bank 11 Channel 14? FM

Comment: @Hearth I'm understanding this question more as a "how do I go ahed and analyze this? question

Comment: No, Heath, as you can see, I asked for the kind of modulation. And I only gave some further information about the used band (maybe it is a specific kind of modulation and of possible Transmitter). Thank you, Sunnyskyguy EE75 & Marcus Müller

Comment: That's right in the middle of the uplink frequency now used for LTE Band 20. It was formerly used for analogue TV transmissions but freed up across Europe by the digital switchover.